# Cant build V8 with GYP successfully on Mac OSX

Tags: gcc, g++, v8, embedded-v8

I followed V8 Build Instructions from [here](https://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/BuildingWithGYP)

Here are the steps that I'm following to build V8 on Mac OSX.

```
1. git clone git://github.com/v8/v8.git v8-src && cd v8-src
2. make dependencies
3. make x64 -j8 library=shared snapshot=on console=readline
```

But I do not see `out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.x64.a (or snapshot.a)`

The Folder only contains `js2c.stamp`

Here is the `Gist:` [Build Output](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/174c0d71649670dfddcf)

What am I doing wrong ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the documentation specifies the location for Linux Machines. For Mac OSX, these files are here :

`out/x64.release/libv8_base.x64.a (& snapshot.a)`

Finally, compile your C++ Module, by linking V8, as below:

`g++ -Iinclude test.cc -o test out/x64.release/libv8_{base.x64,snapshot}.a -lpthread`